# Why is this '_' used in the third line? Python2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I am using python to learn about data science. Everything is fine but recently I found below code in a book. I can't understand for what purpose **'_'** is being used.

```
def raw_majority_vote(labels):
    votes = Counter(labels)
    winner, _ = votes.most_common(1)[0]
    return winner
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this piece of code you posted, the `_` is a variable name.

You can assign values to `_`.

I.e.:

```
>>> _ = "test"
>>> print _
```

Output:

```
test
```

If you take a look at [`Counter.most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) docs, you'll see this message:

> Return a list of the n most common elements and their counts from the
>   most common to the least. If n is omitted or None, most_common()
>   returns all elements in the counter. Elements with equal counts are
>   ordered arbitrarily:
>
> ```
> >>> Counter('abracadabra').most_common(3)
> [('a', 5), ('r', 2), ('b', 2)]
> ```

So, in your code, `winner, _ = votes.most_common(1)[0]`

The variable `winner` gets the first value of the first tuple contained in this most_common list.
And the variable, `_`, gets the second value of the first tuple in this list.

In this case:

```
winner = 'a'
_ = 5
```

Comment: Thanks , it's such a normal point. Why am I not tried this ?

Answer (score 1):

It's a throwaway variable. Whatever `votes.most_common(1)[0]` is can be unpacked to two values and the writer of that script is only interested in the first value.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is used when you don't care about returned variable and you want to discard it but still prevent any `ValueError`s.